# CoreData works but returns one more nil object in the console?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

First of all thanks in advance for any help provided, thank you for your time :)

I don't have any bugs or issues, but my console is printing nils when fetching data with **Core Data & Swift 4**.

Here is my code :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


 //Fetch from Core Data

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")


        //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                print(data.value(forKey: "username") as Any) // ou as? String
                print(data.value(forKey: "date_naissance") as Any) // ou as? String
            }

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
```

Here is my console output:

> Optional(julien) Optional(1994-09-09 04:34:00 +0000) nil nil

If I fetch for only one value, then the console shows only one nil.
Every value printed gets a nil.

Also, my previous code was

```
print(data.value(forKey: "username") as! String)
```

But it crashed after printing the value in the console (the value got printed though).

So I fixed it by printing as Any, but now I get nils after.

I would just like to know if this is normal since it does not affect my app for the moment but it will probably soon.

Thank you for your time, help and support :)

Have a wonderful day!
Julien

Comment: Please print `data` and add the result to the question. And don't use old-fashioned syntax. If your entity is `Users` create a fetch request `NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")` and use dot notation instead of primitive KVC.

Comment: It simply means that you have a user object for which those properties were never set – you probably defined them as *optional* properties in the  Core Data model inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code with the loop into this

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
         if let userName = data.value(forKey: "username") as? String {
              print(userName)
          }
          if let dateNaissance = data.value(forKey: "date_naissance") as? String {
              print(dateNaissance)
          }
        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
```

Check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/) of optional

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys for your help.

I did what seemed the more logical to me (even if I should write better my code, that is true).

Thank you Βασίλης Δ, vadian (and also wvteijlingen for editing my post). :)

So Martin got the answer, I post it here so it is marked as solved, thank you Martin. I took "optional" off my CoreData Model and I do not get those nil values printed now anymore, so that is cool :)

Have a wonderful day guys and thank you so much! :)